# How to design String decollator in a string contains many params

Tags: java, string

I need pass a string parameter that contains many params. When receive the parameter, I use String.split() to split it to get all the params.
But one promblem accured. **How to design my string decollator so that any ASCII CODE on keyboard can be passed correctly.**
Hope for any advice.

Comment: Can you give an example of what is not currently working for you?

Comment: @user1515834 for example, if I use "|", I can't pass params that contain symble "|". Otherwise it will split at the symble.

Comment: Is the user entering this parameter, or are you passing it between your own methods?

Comment: @user1515834 Is there any way to solve it? I want to find a perfect solution so that I needn't to consern this question any longer.

Comment: @JacobRaihle User enters them, and I must consern every condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could have a look at [variadic arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) instead of splitting a string. For example:

```
public void method(String... strings) {
    // strings is actually an array
    String firstParam = strings[0];
    String secondParam = strings[1];
    // ...
}
```

Calling:

```
method("string1");
method("string1", "string2", "string3");
// as many string args as you want
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. But if I change my code like that, much code associated will be recoded. Is there any solution under my limiting conditions? Thank you again.

Comment: In that case, you can either use @mudalov solution, or you could also auto-escape the separator char you chose each time the user entered it as part of the value of a param.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly - you need to encode set of parameters to one string. You can use some sequence of characters for this purpose, E.g.

```
final String delimiter = "@#@"
String value = "param1@#@param2@#@param3";
String[] parameters = value.split(delimiter);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've considered this solution but... don't you think it's a little ...clumsy? I'm looking for one ingenious answer.

Comment: Firstly, the idea to pass parameters in this way is not so ingenious ..) Parameters could be encoded using standard mechanisms, e.g. JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a character which is easy to enter and unlikely to appear in the input. Let's assume that character is `#`.

Normal input would like like `Item 1#Item 2#Item 3`. Actually, you can `.trim()` every item and let the user enter `Item 1 # Item 2 # Item 3` if s/he prefers.

However, like you describe, say the user would like to enter `Item #1`, `Item #2`, etc.. There are a few ways to let him/her do this, but the easier is to let them *escape* the delimiter. For example, instead of `Item #1 # Item #2 # Item #3`, which would result in 6 different items being found normally, let the user enter, for example `Item ##1 # Item ##2 # Item ##3`. Then in your parsing, make sure to handle the case when two or more `#`'s have been entered in a row. `split` likely won't be good enough, you'll have to go through the string yourself.

Here's a sketch of a method which would split the input string for you:

```
private static List<String> parseArguments(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> arguments = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] prelArguments = input.split("#");
    for (int i = 0; i < prelArguments.length; i++) {
        String argument = prelArguments[i];
        if (argument.equals("")) {
            // We will enter here if there were two or more #'s in a row
            StringBuilder combinedArgument = new StringBuilder(arguments.remove(arguments.size() - 1));
            int inARow = 0;
            while (prelArguments[i+inARow].equals("")) {
                inARow++;
                combinedArgument.append('#');
            }
            i += inARow;
            combinedArgument.append(prelArguments[i]);
            arguments.add(combinedArgument.toString());
        } else {
            arguments.add(argument);
        }
    }
    return arguments;
}
```

Error handling, edge-case handling and some performance improvement is missing from the above, but I think the idea comes through.

Answer (score 1):

I would eliminate the *problem,* which is the misuse of String as an argument container. If you need to pass more parameters, pass more parameters. If this gets out of hand, consider passing a map, or a custom object that can contain all the parameters.